# What methods can composers use to make the listener's perception of time feel slower or faster?

Tags: composition

When composing or arranging, what methods can be exploited to affect the listener's perception of the speed they are moving through time?

Comment: Bagpipes are capable of stopping time altogether, in the listener's perception ;))

Comment: Do you mean going back in history/ forward into the future, or simply in the here and now? It's not clear from the wording of the question as it stands.

Comment: Write really tedious and boring music, and the audience will think that time is passing really slowly.

Comment: There's actually a lot to discuss here—there's a lot of scholarly work about perception of time in general, and [a lot about "time" as a broad concept in music](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Making_Musical_Time/D8lOEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)—but can you edit to add a bit more about how you're thinking about it? Are there any examples that you find alter your perception of time? For instance, how do you feel about https://youtu.be/mr4Z99G-Yc4 or https://youtu.be/TJ6Mzvh3XCc ? What about https://youtu.be/g0WVh1D0N50 or https://youtu.be/miUKO5g0ONk ?

Comment: (For transparency, those four examples are "vert fast tempo with very short notes," "very slow tempo with very long notes," "very gradual change while looping a short chunk of time," and "exploring 'time' while dispensing with the concept of 'beat.'")

Answer (score 0):

1. Slow down or increase in **tempo**. That's an effective way to do it.
2. Change **time division**. E.g. when playing quarter notes, switching to eight notes will feel faster, while switsching to half notes will feel slower, though the tempo remains the same.
3. Change **accentuation**. The standard accents are on "1" in 4/4, i.e. emphasizing each 4th quarter note. But, like drummers do, you can emphasize each 5th, 6th and so on to overlay a slower varying pattern. Or emphasize every 3rd or 2nd to overlay a faster one. Consider subdivision of quarter notes as well for more granularity. Consider asymmetric pattern overlays, like 3-3-2 (8), or 3-2-3 (8) or 2-3-2 (7), which also change the period of repetiton.